# Keep Gantt Chart range conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have Gantt Chart (Sheet1) and would like to copy and paste predefined Tasks from (Sheet2). Problem with current solution is that Conditional formatting is not applied to newly pasted rows as there is no conditional formatting on copied cells. I have tried to apply Conditional formatting on Sheet2 but then there is a lot of Conditional formatting's and formula for conditional formatting is connected to Sheet2 so it is not working correct after copying on Sheet1.

Sheet2 = Data

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
Sub InsertRev()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim c As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5000")
    For dblCounter = Rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set c = Rng(dblCounter)
        If c.Value Like "Last" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Rows("26:27").Copy
        c.EntireRow.insert
    End If
    Next dblCounter

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```